$1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2=y^2$ ($n$ and $y$ are natural numbers)
I tried solving this so first $1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$ so problem is $n(n+1)(2n+1)=6y^2$ where $n$ and $y$ are natural. I tried doing this $n=6k,6k+1....6k+5$, so say for $n=6k$
you get $k(6k+1)(12k+1)=y^2$ so $k(6k+1)$ and $12k+1$ are co-prime which means they are all squares meaning $k=a^2 \quad 6k+1=b^2\quad 12k+1=c^2$ but idk what to do from here?
Whatever I try I can't solve this.
ps. I'm pretty sure $n=24, y=70$ is the only solution besides $1,1$.

MSE MathJax Tutorial.

See art of problem solving. The unique solution is indeed $n=24$ and $y=70$, see also the duplicate (please try to search next time before posting).

Or google "cannonball problem".

A better duplicate might be this one, or this one by the way. But there are very many.

None of the other questions actually have a solution to the problem, mostly just links to payblocked articles.  Which not only violates the "link only answers" standard but does so in a really bad way.  The "already answered" question is to a different problem than the one asked here.

@DietrichBurde you should change the dupe target, as it does not answer the question directly.

@DietrichBurde FYI, your "Yes, but I don't know how to change this" implies to me that you're unaware of how to change the list of duplicate questions. If so, then as a "number-theory" gold-tag member, note that in the upper-right hand corner of the blue square, you should see a little pencil type icon, with "Edit" after it. The tool-tip for it says "Edit the list of duplicate questions". Clicking on this replaces the page with a new one where it shows the current list of duplicate questions, along with options to remove from and/or add to the list.

@JohnOmielan Thank you very much. In the future I know how to do it.
